# How to get fill-paragraph in a scala multi-line comment to wrap?

Tags: fill-paragraph

Emacs is my weapon of choice for documenting code, not least because of its great support for formatting comments. However, there is one thing that is slowing me down in scala-mode2. When I have a line that starts with an `@param` annotation the `fill-paragraph` function does not wrap the line. If I remove the `@` from the `@param` then the `fill-paragraph` works. So I find myself writing some docs about a parameter, removing the `@` from `@param`, running `fill-paragraph`, and then adding the `@` back in.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * param without the leading @ character fill-paragraph is happy to
 * wrap this line.
 * 
 * @param with the leading @ character fill-paragraph is refuses to wrap this line.
 */
class BlahBlah
```

The only Scala customization variable I have set is `(scala-indent:use-javadoc-style t)`. The issue persists when set to `nil`.

I'm using emacs 24.5.1 with the latest scala-mode2 from the public repos (20150617.2350) -- just upgraded from a 201407 version that had the same problem.